# 2nd order homogeneous difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$a_{n+2} = 9a_{n+1} - 18a_n,\quad  n\geq 0,\,\,a_0=1,\,\, a_1=3$$

I got to the point where i moved all to LHS which gives me $a_{n+2} - 9 a_{n+1} + 18 a_n$ (correct me if I'm wrong). I then calculated to the point of getting the roots 3 & 6. From there i don't really know how to get the ''$a_n$''. Could anyone point if i made any mistakes so far and help me get the an?

Thank you

Comment: Could someone edit the an+2 etc, i'm new and have no idea how to do those :(

Comment: Put all math equations between two `$`, then write `a_{n+2}`, etc.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón ahh thank you!

Comment: Well if the roots are 3 and 6, then an= C1*(3)^n + c2*(6)^n. So now what you have to do is solve this equation for n=0 and n=1 to see what are the values of C1 and C2.I think you can handle it.

Comment: @user109218 I would get a simultaneous equation then calculate for A & B?

Comment: you have 1=c1 + c2 and 3=c1*3 + c2*6 from here c1=1 and c2=0

Comment: @user109218 Yeah i got that, so An = 3^n ?

Comment: Yes.That is right.Just write down some of the sequence and you will see ti.

Answer (score 1):

You write the *characteristic equation*: $r^2=9r-18$ which give you $r_1=3,r_2=6$. The general term has the form $a\cdot 3^n+b\cdot 6^n$. To find $a,b$ you use the relations $a_1=3,a_0=1$ which will give you a $2 \times 2$ system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

A general method uses generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, multiply your recurrence by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$. You recognize several sums:
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2} = 9 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} - 18 A(z)
$$
Substituting initial values, solving for $A(z)$ and writing as partial fractions:
$$
A(z) = \frac{1}{1 - 3 z}
$$
so that $a_n = 3^n$. This checks out substituted in the recurrence.